# TCP/IP networking speed up with C#

Tags: c#, performance, tcp

I have 2 machine(PC) with communication via TCP/IP. I have an simple application which has Server/Client program.

When I measure the speed of communication between 2 machine, then I got 400 ~ 500 msec from sending/receiving message.

Is it limitation of speed between 2 machin via TCP/IP ? or is there any best way to speed up the communication ?

Any comment would be helpful for me.

**Update**

Here is my Tcp configuration. Data is just string under 10 bytes.

```
[5908] System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket Tcp Socket configured:
[5908] System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket   ExclusiveAddressUse False
[5908] System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket   LingerState False, 0
[5908] System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket   NoDelay False
[5908] System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket   ReceiveBufferSize 8192
[5908] System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket   ReceiveTimeout 0
[5908] System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket   SendBufferSize 8192
[5908] System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket   SendTimeout 0
[5908] System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket   Ttl 128
[5908] System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket   IsBound True
```

Comment: What kind of data you're trying to send? is that a File or some test data?

Comment: Just string message under 10 bytes.

Comment: ->>>System SocketCommCoreUnit::ConfigureTcpSocket NoDelay False (should be True!!)

Answer (score 5):

There is a tcp option called NoDelay.

[Socket.nodelay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay.aspx)

It is the Nagle-Algo switch. The Nagle-Algo buffers by default a certain amount of bytes before sending it. For low latency stuff you should enable "nodelay".